# Migrar do PHP 5.2.9 para PHP 5.6.8

Tags: php, atualização

Tenho um sistema de gerenciamento de uma armazém feito sobre o PHP 5.2.9 todo sistema  esta rodando em apache. Os arquivos estão com extensão .php5, como posso migrar este sistema de forma a diminuir o impacto no todo sistema ? Bem como alterar a extensão .php5 para .php ??

Comment: A extensão php5 é customizada, provavelmente você terá que editar em todos arquivos os links e formulário que usam a extensão .php5 primeiro, abrindo-os (todos) em um editor como sublimetext e apertar Ctrl+Shift+F e substituir .php5 por .php e depois de salva-los renomear um arquivo por um. Realmente não entendo a tag `princípios-de-programação` na pergunta, a questão me parece apenas migração.

Comment: Além da parte do Apache, bastante coisas precisaram ser alteradas no se código. Muita coisa foi descontinuada entre o [PHP 5.2 até o 5.6](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration53.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A extensão `php5` é customizada, em outras palavras não tem nada haver com a versão do php, já que no Apache (suponho que este possa ser o seu servidor) pode usar a extensão que você desejar.

O que provavelmente você terá que fazer é:

1. Editar em todos arquivos os links e formulário que usam a extensão `.php5` primeiro, abra-os (todos) em um editor como sublimetext3 e apertar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. Substitua `.php5` por `.php` e depois de salva-los renomear um arquivo por um.

### Apache

Se você quiser manter a extensão `.php5`, você pode fazer o upgrade do seu apache e php e então editar o httpd.conf do Apache e adicionar a extensão `.php5` e adicione algo como isto:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php5
</IfModule>
```

### Nginx

Se o seu servidor for Nginx, você pode editar o arquivo `nginx.conf`, como no exemplo (é apenas um exemplo, cuidado ao editar):

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(|5)(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php(|5))(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

### Lighttpd

No lighttpd edite primeiro o arquivo `lighttpd.conf` e procure uma linha semelhante a está:

```
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".cgi" )
```

Altere para:

```
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php5", ".php", ".pl", ".cgi" )
```

e depois procure a linha que semelhante a `fastcgi.server = (` e `fastcgi.map-extensions = (`, deve ficar algo como:

```
fastcgi.server             = ( ".php" =>
                               ( "localhost" =>
                                 (
                                   "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                                   "port" => 9000
                                 )
                               )
                             )

## map multiple extensions to the same fastcgi server
fastcgi.map-extensions     = ( ".php5" => ".php" )
```